# How to do SAML SSO redirect in Java

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to do a SAML redirect in Java but it is failing.

The initial request works and I get the following response:

```
2019-06-29 18:34:59,069 18:34:59.069 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:16) - Starting test...
2019-06-29 18:35:04,596 18:35:04.596 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:19) - Sending request to: https://sso.rallydev.com/sp/startSSO.ping?PartnerIdpId=my.company.identifier
2019-06-29 18:35:05,420 18:35:05.420 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:22) - Got response: 

<!-- template name: form.autopost.template.html -->


<html>
    <head>
    <title>Submit Form</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
       <noscript>
            <p>
                <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the Resume button once to proceed.
            </p>
        </noscript>
        <form method="post" action="https://ssopacorp2extra.mycompany.com/idp/SSO.saml2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="aBigLONgStrINGOfGobblidyGOok=="/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="aShortERSTRingOfGOBBlidygOOK"/>
                        <noscript><input type="submit" value="Resume"/></noscript>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I then send the form data from the response I get an empty reply with no headers and a status of 0.

If I then try to access the page I am actually trying to get to I get the errors shown below.

```
2019-06-29 19:05:33,242 19:05:33.242 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:41) - Sending request to: https://ssopacorp2extra.mycompany.com/idp/SSO.saml2
2019-06-29 19:05:33,664 19:05:33.664 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:44) - STATUS: 0
2019-06-29 19:05:33,664 19:05:33.664 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:45) - Got response: 

2019-06-29 19:05:33,664 19:05:33.664 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:46) - Done with saml2 request
2019-06-29 19:05:33,664 19:05:33.664 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:50) - Getting ca agile data...
2019-06-29 19:05:33,669 19:05:33.669 [main] INFO  (GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:54) - Sending request to: https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/165441981268d/dashboard
2019-06-29 19:05:33,733 19:05:33.733 [main] INFO  (RetryExec.java:97) - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://rally1.rallydev.com:443: Connection reset
2019-06-29 19:05:33,734 19:05:33.734 [main] INFO  (RetryExec.java:113) - Retrying request to {s}->https://rally1.rallydev.com:443
2019-06-29 19:05:33,796 19:05:33.796 [main] INFO  (RetryExec.java:97) - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://rally1.rallydev.com:443: Connection reset
2019-06-29 19:05:33,796 19:05:33.796 [main] INFO  (RetryExec.java:113) - Retrying request to {s}->https://rally1.rallydev.com:443
2019-06-29 19:05:33,862 19:05:33.862 [main] INFO  (RetryExec.java:97) - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://rally1.rallydev.com:443: Connection reset
2019-06-29 19:05:33,862 19:05:33.862 [main] INFO  (RetryExec.java:113) - Retrying request to {s}->https://rally1.rallydev.com:443
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.mycompany.myproject.util.http.HttpRequestClient.doGet(HttpRequestClient.java:162)
    at com.mycompany.myproject.excel.GetCaAgileDataManualTest.getCaAgileData(GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:55)
    at com.mycompany.myproject.excel.GetCaAgileDataManualTest.main(GetCaAgileDataManualTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.mycompany.myproject.util.http.HttpRequestClient.doGet(HttpRequestClient.java:158)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Is your app acting as a spec compliant SAML Service Provider entity? Which SAML protocol binding are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the download of a csv file from a web site that I normally access through SSO.  The file is coming from CA Agile.  I have the url for the file, but when I try to access it I get the html form response shown in the question ("submit this form to continue").  What I'm really trying to do is access a SAML/SSO secured web page from java.

Comment: In fact the so called ECP profile was meant for this use case , please see http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf

However not many IdPs implement this, so you may have to mimic the WebBrowser SSO profile, i.e. read the responses from the SP/IdP and send it over to the other SAML entity.